# how to fit a tiling of figures on to one page

Tags: floats

I hate working with figures in Latex. I can't seem to get a handle on them. Anyways, please consider the following screenshot.

[image]
**

### Code

```
\begin {table}[H]
    \caption {Effect of $\beta, r$ on the Basic Reproduction Number $R_0$}          \label{tab:table1} 
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSS} \toprule    

        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end {table}

\begin{figure}[H]    
    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot03}
    \end{minipage}

    \hspace{\fill}

    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot05}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{0.2cm} % (or whatever vertical separation you prefer)

    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot06}
    \end{minipage}

    \hspace{\fill}

    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot12}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

### Problem

I want the gap between the two columns to be smaller and the graphs a little bigger. There are 4 graphs but there is too much whitespace. If I made the minipage bigger `{0.5\textwidth}` all four move to the next page which I don't want. If I make the width of the image bigger, then it dosn't scale properly (the graph will occupy some of the other graphs area).

Comment: Your `\hspace{\fill}` commands are telling LaTeX to place the two graphics as far apart as possible. Change to the desired spacing, e.g., `\hspace{0.5cm}`. You might also want to remove spurious spaces between the `minipage`s and spacing commands to ensure that the spacing you enter in the code is what you actually get in the output.

Comment: I got rid of the `hspace, vspace` so that helped. It didnt increase the size of the graphs but brought them closer together.  Is there a way to scale them all a little bigger?

Comment: Either increase the width of the `minipage`s or increase the width of the included graphics...

Comment: Have you looked at the `subcaption` package. It opens a `subfigure` environment which could also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When placing a set of four minipages (each of which will contain a graph), don't insert blank lines between the first and second and between the third and fourth minipages.

Minipages don't float, so the "h" placement directive after `\begin{minipage}` doesn't do anything.

The reason why your images don't look big enough could be that they aren't cropped tightly. Check if there's noticeable whitespace around them. If that's the case, cropping the surrounding whitespace will allow the actual images to become (much) bigger.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,float,siunitx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to indicate width of text block

\begin{table}[H]
\caption {Effect of $\beta$ and $r$ on Basic Reproduction Number $R_0$} \label{tab:table1} 
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SSSS SSSS} 
\toprule    
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot03}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot05}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{1cm} % vertical separation

    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot06}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plots/Rplot12}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Figure caption goes here} \label{fig:4pics}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```